# efficient way to write this query - audit histroy on created and modified

Tags: sql, sql-server

just wondering if there is a better and more efficient way of creating this query as the below is taking a long time as this query is being run for every table in the database catalogue. Thank you

```
    Select N'MSCRM_REPORTING'  As [Database], N'dbo' As [Schema], N'apuk_erqanswerBase' As [Table], N'ModifiedOn' As ChangeType,
    sum(case when DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0,ModifiedOn), 0) between DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()), 0) -7 AND DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()), 0)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [0-7 Days],
    sum(case when DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0,ModifiedOn), 0) between DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()), 0)-28 AND DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()), 0)- 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [8-28 Days],
    sum(case when DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0,ModifiedOn), 0) between DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()), 0)-84 AND DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()), 0)-29 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [29-84 Days],
    sum(case when DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0,ModifiedOn), 0) between DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()), 0)-182 AND DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()), 0)-85 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [85-182 Days],
    sum(case when DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, ModifiedOn), 0) BETWEEN convert(datetime,0) and DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()), 0) - 183 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [183+],
    sum(case when ModifiedOn is null then 1 else 0 end) [NullRows],
    count(*) as [RowCount]
    From MSCRM_REPORTING.dbo.apuk_erqanswerBase
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having multiple DATEDIFFs will be costly, so why not try getting the difference between the dates in a subquery and using that within the SELECT:

```
Select N'MSCRM_REPORTING'  As [Database], N'dbo' As [Schema], N'apuk_erqanswerBase' As [Table], N'ModifiedOn' As ChangeType,
sum(case when a.Days BETWEEN 0 AND 7  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [0-7 Days],
sum(case when a.Days BETWEEN 8 AND 28 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [8-28 Days],
sum(case when a.Days BETWEEN 29 AND 84 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [29-84 Days],
sum(case when a.Days BETWEEN 85 AND 182 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [85-182 Days],
sum(case when a.Days >= 183 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [183+],
sum(case when ModifiedOn is null then 1 else 0 end) [NullRows],
count(*) as [RowCount]
From 
(
    Select  DATEDIFF(dd, ModifiedOn, getdate()) AS [Days], 
            ModifiedOn
    From    MSCRM_REPORTING.dbo.apuk_erqanswerBase
) a
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as well:

```
Select N'MSCRM_REPORTING'  As [Database], 
    N'dbo' As [Schema], 
    N'apuk_erqanswerBase' As [Table], 
    N'ModifiedOn' As ChangeType,
    sum(case when DATEDIFF(dd, ModifiedOn, getdate()) BETWEEN 0 AND 7  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [0-7 Days],
    sum(case when DATEDIFF(dd, ModifiedOn, getdate()) BETWEEN 8 AND 28 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [8-28 Days],
    sum(case when DATEDIFF(dd, ModifiedOn, getdate()) BETWEEN 29 AND 84 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [29-84 Days],
    --------------------- 
from MSCRM_REPORTING.dbo.apuk_erqanswerBase
```